# android programming: showing 75% of a bitmap via ClipDrawable (eclipse)

Tags: android, imageview, clip

I'm going to show 75% of a bitmap in an ImageView.
searched every where and realized that I should use clip drawable.
searched again but found no guide for doing this in eclipse.
please help !

thanks alot

Comment: did you read `android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable` documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: yes I did . But I need an example. something like full source of the activity

Comment: no whats unclear in the docs? what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know what the code should be like

Comment: sorry I'm not very professional ;D

Comment: then create your clip drawable like here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip and use `ImageView#setImageLevel` method to set the level you want

Comment: almost got it...